# DB connection Yii Framework

Tags: mysql, yii

I've got a new domain & hosting but I can't connect to the new db.

What I tried:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=ascodcurro.com.mysql;dbname=ascodcurro_com',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'ascodcurro_com',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

If I try localhost as always it works fine.
User info from host:

```
MySQL   
server: ascodcurro.com.mysql
DB: ascodcurro_com
user:   ascodcurro_com
pw: *****

PhpMyAdmin  
PhpMyAdmin: https://dbadmin.one.com/
user:   ascodcurro_com
pw: ******
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the initial startup and working with Yii, the first problem that I faced was connecting to the database.

I was getting a really weird error and I was not able to connect to my DB on my Mac OSX Mountain Lion on my XAMPP stack. After countless searches, I finally figured out a method that worked. This is the only way I am able to connect to my DB for Yii.

1. First check if you can connect to the database normally using the
   default configuration by uncommenting the 'db' configuration in the
   main.php file.   Example :

   ```
   'db'=>array(

               'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ascodcurro_com',
               'emulatePrepare' => true,
               'username' => 'username',
               'password' => 'pass',
               'charset' => 'utf8',
               'tablePrefix'=>'',
               'enableProfiling'=>true,
               'enableParamLogging'=>true,


           ),
   ```

However, if you are still not able to connect to the database even after this, as I wasn't able to connect to mine, try taking this approach : 
Make a new php file and type :

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

check that page out, find out where '*mysql*' is located and find out the '**MYSQL_SOCKET**' in it and note the location.

After noting the location down, try this as your 'db' connection string(for example, for me the location is "*/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock*") :

```
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=practice',
```

And the rest as the basic parameters that you use.
And then try connecting again.

Hopefully, that should connect you to your DB.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
'db'=>array(

            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basename',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix'=>'',
            'enableProfiling'=>true,
            'enableParamLogging'=>true,


        ),
```

its my config. You get any errors?